# How to pass ostream operator<< as a function in C++?

Tags: c++

Is there any way I can pass an `std::ostream operator<<` as an argument in other function call? For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename Visitor>
void print(Visitor v, int value)
{
    v(value);
}

int main(void)
{

    std::cout.operator<<(5); // This works

    std::cout << 5; // This works

    print(std::cout.operator<<, 5); // Error happens

    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```sh
$ g++ -g main.cpp -o main
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:17:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘print(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int)’
           5);
            ^
main.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: template<class Visitor> void print(Visitor, int)
 void print(Visitor v, int value)
      ^~~~~
main.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:17:12: note:   could not deduce template parameter "Visitor"
```

I know in C++ we can do operator overloadings like `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, something);` but that's not what I aim to. Let's say I want to work with other printing functions or operators (like `std::fout` or `printf`), so I want my `print` function to be generic as much as possible.

Comment: As long as your function accepts `std::ostream&` as a parameter, it'll work just fine. https://ideone.com/AZZnr5

Comment: This particular `operator<<` is not an [addressable function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std#Addressable_functions) and so cannot be passed as an argument to another function in this manner. Depending on what exactly you're trying to do and why you believe you need to structure your `print` function this way, a different approach may be feasible.

Comment: You need to pass a pointer or reference to the function, the object the function is a member of, and the value to pass to this function. Or use lambdas if you only want to pass a function.

Comment: I haven't tried your answers yet but @songyuanyao answer works for me!

Comment: There are few circumstances in which is is appropriate to pass an `operator<<()` as an argument of a function. It will also be problematic for streams, as some `operator<<()` are member functions of classes in the standard library (`std::basic_ostream`, etc) and some are non-member functions.  So it is more usual to pass the stream and the object, and connect them using an expression like `astream << an_object` - the compiler will then sort out calling an appropriate `operator<<()` (or diagnosing an error) - whether that function is a member of the stream or a non-member - as needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a lambda instead.

```
print([](int value) { std::cout << value; }, 5);
```

Comment: I swear I had tried lambda before, i guess I had messed up somewhere! This answer works for me! Thank you!

Comment: can you demonstrate the complete example please!

Comment: @AndreasHadjigeorgiou Like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/w5whYnKaCRZq2mPZ)?